# dcast with empty left-hand side in formula

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm having problems with using `dcast` withoud "id" variables. The expected result is basically a transposition -- creating a 1-row data frame with as many columns as there are rows in the original data frame.

I've tried different approaches, but only "hacks" seem to work for now. Before [filing a bug](https://github.com/hadley/reshape/issues), I wanted to double-check if I'm missing something.

```
d <- data.frame(variable=letters[1:3], value=1:3)
d

##   variable value
## 1        a     1
## 2        b     2
## 3        c     3

reshape2::dcast(d, ...~variable)

##   . a b c
## 1 . 1 2 3

reshape2::dcast(d, .~variable)

##   . a b c
## 1 . 1 2 3

reshape2::dcast(d, ~variable)

## Error: subscript out of bounds

reshape2::dcast(d, 0~variable)

##   0 a b c
## 1 0 1 2 3

sessionInfo()

## R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base     
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] evaluate_0.5.6 formatR_1.0    knitr_1.6.18   methods_3.1.1 
##  [5] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.2    reshape2_1.4   stringr_0.6.2 
##  [9] tools_3.1.1    ulimit_0.0-2
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is `dcast` creating the odd and useless `.` column when using `...~variable` or `.~variable` as formula?

Comment: Looking at the code this seems to be by design.

Comment: Why not use the t() function?

Comment: @Roland: Thanks. Could you provide a reference please?

Comment: @BondedDust: `t(d)` is not quite what I need. I'm fine with what `reshape2::dcast(d, 0~variable)` returns, except for the extra `0` column.

Comment: I just looked at `reshape2:::cast`. There you find `labels[is_empty] <- rep(list(data.frame(. = ".")), sum(is_empty))`, which looks intentional. Btw. you get the same with `reshape2::dcast(d, NULL~variable)`.